# Change from wired network to wireless (wireless->wired) relogin outlook and skype for business

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, skype, kerberos

Whenever I change from my wired network to my wireless network of the other way around. I'm prompted to challenge my credentials again. How can I set this up that I don't have to this again.
[relogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzIYg.png)

Comment: Is it happening in your workplace or at home? Did you tried to just select "remember credentials"?

Comment: This happens everywhere home, work. Yes I did tick remember credentials.